# How to run a function asynchronously in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I want to run my function asynchronously, but how do I do that?:

```
    checkLocation() {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, Promise, function* () {
            while (true) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(
                        (isAvailable) => {
                            console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
                            if (!isAvailable) {
                                alert('Please turn on the location service');
                            }
                        }).catch((e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                        });
                }, 5000)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

One of the discovered problems is that TS cannot fine name `__awaiter`. I have tried to follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/03/what-about-asyncawait/)

Comment: We have no way of knowing why `__awaiter` isn't available above from the code in the question. It has nothing whatsoever to do with sync/async.

Comment: I just tried to follow the link I posted. That's why I am asking you guys :)

Comment: `__awaiter` isn't something **you** write. It's output by the TypeScript compiler if you us `async`/`await` functions. From your link: *"For the sample above, the TypeScript compiler emits the below ES6 JavaScript for the `ping` function."* As that's quite clearly saying, the code including `__awaiter` is **output** of the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: What is it you want your function to actually do?

Comment: I want the function `checkLocation()` to run asynchronously

Comment: What do you want it to ***do*** asynchronously? What parts of that code are actually yours as opposed to some boilerplate you picked up somewhere? Note that `while (true)` starting `setTimeout` with no loop break is **not** a good idea.

Comment: I should check if the location service (on the phone) is enabled asynchronously

Comment: The whole code is mine except for the part `return __awaiter(this, void 0, Promise, function* () {}` I took that from the website I linked

Comment: Why did you add a call to `__awaiter`? It's hard to infer your intent because of the while loop and the timeout as noted by Crowder.

Comment: Because I thought it was the right way to run the function asynchronously

Comment: Well since that is not the case I suggest you go back to basics with promises and async functions. Get a few simple examples working and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `__awaiter` isn't something **you** write. It's output by the TypeScript compiler if you us `async`/`await` functions.

Re what you said you want to do:

> [It] should check if the location service (on the phone) is enabled asynchronously

The check will be asynchronous regardless, because `this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled` is asynchronous.

The `async`/`await` way to write `checkLocation` would be to make it an `async` method, which would consume the promise from `isLocationEnabled` via `await`:

```
async checkLocation() {
    const isAvailable = await this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled();
    console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
    if (!isAvailable) {
        alert('Please turn on the location service');
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

The non-`async`/`await` version of that is this using promises explicitly:

```
checkLocation() {
    return this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(isAvailable => {
        console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
        if (!isAvailable) {
            alert('Please turn on the location service');
        }
        return isAvailable;
    });
}
```

Note that I've removed the `catch` handler, because by returning the promise you're deferring error handling to the caller.

If `checkLocation` is meant to be fire-and-forget rather than returning the (promise of) the flag, then you wouldn't use an `async` function at all and wouldn't return the promise (and so would keep the `catch`):

```
checkLocation() {
    this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(isAvailable => {
        console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
        if (!isAvailable) {
            alert('Please turn on the location service');
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: It would be your last suggestion. However, if I want it to keep running can't I put a while loop before     `this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(isAvailable => {`?

Comment: @GeorgeW: What do you mean "keep it running"? Hopefully you don't mean you want to constantly `alert` the user?

Comment: I mean it should keep showing the alert as long as `isAvailable` is false. It's needed as the application needs the users location in order to work properly

Comment: @GeorgeW: The nature of `alert` is that it will keep showing until the user dismisses it. If you're saying you want to repeatedly `alert` until the user allows location services, that's a very, very, very bad idea because it gets in the way of the user enabling location services and is irritating to the user, driving them away from the app. Instead, just put the app in a state where it says it can't run because it needs location services, with a button or similar the user can click to say "I've turned them on now." You'd have that button trigger `checkLocation` again.